# Is there an error in this code? If so, where

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, implicit-conversion

I have my homework pending as I cannot understand this code. Is there any error in this code? If so, can you please let me know where.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int *ptr2 = &ptr1;
    printf('%d", **ptr2);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to compile it?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The compiler complains about the `int *ptr2 = &ptr1;` line, doesn't it?  And it complains about `printf("%d", **ptr2)` as well.  I complain about the [`void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) line — it is only vaguely valid on Microsoft systems.  You should use `int main(void)`.  You should also end your `printf()` format with a newline: `printf("%d\n", **ptr2);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh yes! I had the same errors. So, what would the correct code be?

Comment: What [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58446785/15168) looks right to me — and picks up on mismatched quotes which I didn't (but doesn't recommend a newline at the end of the format string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this declaration

```
int *ptr2 = &ptr1;
```

the declared variable and the initializer have different types and there is no implicit conversion from one to another.

You have to write

```
int **ptr2 = &ptr1;
```

And there is a typo in the argument of the printf call

```
printf('%d", **ptr2);
       ^^
```

Must be

```
printf("%d", **ptr2);
```